# Express API endpoint invokation issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, postman

[Network tab showing the DELETE request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70MAL.png)I have created an API in Express js. An endpoint is not reachable by React application. Although the same endpoint can be accessed through Postman.

Express Application

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

import { riskRouter } from './routes/risk.js';
app.use('/api/risk', riskRouter);

app.all('*', async (req, res) => {
  return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Request handler not found!'});
});
```

risk.js contents

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.delete('/listitems/:id', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const listId = req.params.id;
  const { listItems } = req.body

  listItems.forEach(async item => {
    await pool
    .query(`delete from list_items where list_id = ? and item_id = ?`,
      [listId, item.item_id])
    .then((result) => {
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
    });
  });

  return res.status(200).send({ message: 'List items successfully deleted' });
});

export { router as riskRouter }
```

React code for deletion of items:

```
    if (deletedItems.length > 0) {
      let url = `${config.API_URL}/risk/listitems/${listId}`;

      axios
      .delete(url , {listItems: deletedItems}, { headers: { token: jwt } })
      .then((res) => {
        props.setRefresh();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        errorInSave = true;
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

The given code should delete the requested records from table. But whenever I make a request through React, it returns with the following error:

{
message: 'Request handler not found!'
}

When I create an API request from Postman client, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: what is the value of `config.API_URL`? your nodejs endpoint starts with `/api/risk/` but your React code just starts with `/risk`, any chance you missed the `/api`?

Comment: The object is in another file:

const config = {
    API_URL: 'http://localhost:4000/api'
}

export default config

Comment: Open network tab of developer tools and  find that request. Take screentshot and add it in above post.

Comment: @bogdanoff I have added the screenshot.

Comment: @ImranSaeed, have you tried using `http://localhost:4000/api` in your config value? Can you show the details of the error message?

Comment: @ImranSaeed click on that request, a slide bar will popup on right side. take screenshot of it and update it in post